# Is there enough room inside a MacBook Pro 16" to fit a slim Tile?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, security

I'm thinking of upgrading sometime in the future to a 16" MacBook Pro. As someone who keeps my Mac with me on the go, I'm very cautious and alert, but still want to plan for the possibility that it might get taken.

I'm wondering if there's enough room somewhere under the bottom cover to fit one of those ultra slim Tile tags. It would go completely undetected long enough for the laptop to be tracked down, even if Find My Mac wasn't able to phone home.

As janky as it sounds, any smart thief would sit and try around T2 and macOS to disable things, or avoid connecting to the internet. But a random Tile stuck inside the battery compartment is the last thing most of them will think to look for, especially if it blends in with things.

Comment: Why do this when [Apple’s Find My](https://www.apple.com/icloud/find-my/) does this with greater precision and control?

Comment: There is no battery compartment. And judging from this teardown you would be hard pressed to find room for a guitar pick. https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook+Pro+16-Inch+2019+Teardown/128106

Comment: @Allan should the battery die or there not be an internet network it recognizes, it can easily become disconnected. This happens often where I live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can’t fit them.  I have a 2014 MacBook Air and my wife’s friend has those tile key dongles. I folded a piece of paper until it was about the same thickness.

I opened the back and tried to find a place to fit it. Even by the battery where I thought there would be room made the back cover not fit. I was using paper which is more flexible than the plastic tile and I was afraid it would break something. I would definitely not do this

If you want to still use the tile, maybe you could hot glue it to the outside. I like hot glue here because it will stick good and when you want to remove it, it won’t hurt the Mac. I know this because my daughter hot glued rhinestones to her MabBook lid and it didn’t do any damage.

Comment: +1 for an ingenious and safe way to test things out! Making an analogue from flexible material like paper is a smart way to see if  The solution is possible. As for hot glue, I never would have thought [bedazzling](https://binged.it/3eeR2tG) was still a thing!  